# Upload file in Angular 4 and pass it to php file

Tags: angular

I'm trying to upload file in Angular 4 and send it to php with another data like text, when I use var_dumb() to read the data the File Object empty.

My `post.component.html`:

```
<a class="upload-photo-item">
            <input type="file" class="Upload-photo" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" (change)="handleInputChange($event)"/>
            <i class="fa fa-tags olymp-computer-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>

            <h6>Upload Photo</h6>
            <span>Browse your computer.</span>
        </a>
```

And this is `handleInputChange` function:

```
    post = new PostObject();
    image: File;

 handleInputChange(event) {
        console.log(event);
        this.image = event.target.files[0];

        var pattern = /image-*/;

        if (!this.image.type.match(pattern)) {
            console.log('File is not an image');
            return;
        }
        this.post.postPhoto = this.image;

        console.log('image :' + this.image);
  }
```

Everything until now is perfect, I can see my Object file in console, Now here is the problem:

My `post.php`:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($data);
exit;
```

The API response with array(0) like this:
[image]

It can be solved by `base64` but this is not an option for me, any ideas please?

Comment: you can use formdata to send those files to server in ajax way, and receive using $_FILES and $_POST for non file data

Comment: @RoweldeGuzman I tried but I'm sure there is another way, your way is possible with AngularJS, I'm using Angular 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps, how to send formdata in Angular 2+:

```
    import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
    ...
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    ...
    test() {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('data', JSON.stringify({
                test: 'test'
            }));
            formData.append('file', file);

            const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', []);

            // responseType 'text' is necessary for IE
            return this.http.post(url, formData, {
                headers,
                responseType: 'text'
            });
    }
```