# trying to upload file in server (mamp) using php

Tags: php, angular, mamp

I have an `angular` page where I load file, then I call my `php` code to upload to file into my `server`.

It does not work and I got this error for php :

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/my-dropzone-app/upload.php on line 11
```

php code :

```
<?php
  
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   
$folderPath = "http://localhost:8888/test/my-dropzone-app/upload/";
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
   
foreach ($request->fileSource as $key => $value) {
   
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $value);
   
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
   
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
  
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
  
    $file = $folderPath . uniqid() . '.'.$image_type;
  
    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
}

?>
```

angular :

```
  onSelect(event) {
      console.log(event);
      this.files.push(...event.addedFiles);

      const formData = new FormData();
  
      for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) { 
        formData.append("file[]", this.files[i]);
      }
 
      this.http.post('http://localhost:8888/test/my-dropzone-app/upload.php', formData)
      .subscribe(res => {
         console.log(res);
         alert('Uploaded Successfully.');
      })
  }
```

Comment: So what do you get when you do a print_r($request)..?

Comment: thank you for answering. Where can I see the print ? I added it before the loop but in the php_error.log there are not print since it's not an error I guess..

Comment: In your console network tab you should see the reply from that call. You can inspect there what your php script returned

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload file in Angular 4 and pass it to php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882249/upload-file-in-angular-4-and-pass-it-to-php-file)

Comment: @MikeOne I do not have any php file there.. strange